# How can I determine the element is using height or max-height?

Tags: jquery, height, css

How can I determine the element is using `css height` or `css max-height`?

for instance, I have these two elements,

```
<div style="height:100px">fixed</div>
<div style="max-height:100px">max-height</div>
```

I want to change their `height/ max-height` to **100%** when a button is clicked.

```
$('div').height('100%').height();
```

This will only change the first element not the second one.

I was thinking to use if condition to check:

```
if( use height ) $('div').height('100%').height();
else  $('div').css({maxHeight:'100%'}).height();
```

But I don't know how to check... any ideas? or you may have a better idea than mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like the below code to set both of them at once.

```
$('#div').css({height: "100%", maxHeight:"100%"});
```

Hope this is useful!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just test .css('maxHeight').

```
// Returns 'none'
$('img').css('maxHeight')

// Returns '32px'
$('img').css('height')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `$('div').css('max-height')` will give you either the set value or `undefined` or `'none'` as the case may be.

Same goes for `'height'` or any other css property.